# How to prevent POSSIBLE nested promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, ionic3

[ITS NOT DUPLICATED]
the problem is different, but my question is answered below

I'm creating an ionic project where I have to do many promises some of then MAY have anothers promises like this example

```
this.Promise1()
    .then((data) => {
        if(logicTest){
            return this.Promise2()
                .then((data) => {
                    // ...
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // Present error message to the user
                });    
        }
        
        // ...
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Present error message to the user
    })
```

I saw an example where it puts a then down the other, like this

```
this.Promise1()
    .then(() => { ... })
    .then(() => { ... })
```

but how about my example where some times it doesn't return a promise and I need to catch different erros?

## When do I make these nested promises?

- Get the user from the storage to get the API_TOKEN to create the request
- Then I make a request to update an item from a sale list
- Then if two columns of this item have a certain value I make another request to update the sale

Comment: Move the .then.

Comment: @KevinB I updated my quention, see if I'm missing something

Comment: You can't always avoid nesting. (other than maybe with function soup)

Comment: Depending on the context, perhaps an option would be to separate the code within the `if` into a separate function declaration? That way you still get relatively clean separation of code; and, yes, you would still be only performing a series of `.then()`s and `.catch()`s based on a conditional, but then, doesn't that sort of make sense here? There is a sequence you only want to perform on a particular condition, so your code should clearly reflect that; using an if/else makes sense. (If you can't totally separate your code into a separate function, doing it just part-way may work as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in your edit, chaining your promises is the classic way of addressing nested promises. In fact, one of the key purposes of the Promise API was to provide a solution for ["callback hell"](http://callbackhell.com/).

If you'd like to take this a step further, you can also use `async`/`await`. In regards to the previously-deleted answer on compatibility for `async`/`await`, Ionic uses TypeScript and TypeScript transpiles code based on the configured compatibility target. This means that you should be able to use `async`/`await` to simplify your nested or chained promises without issue.

For example:

```
async myFunction() {
    try {
        const data = await this.Promise1();
        if (logicTest) {
            try {
                return await this.Promise2();
            }
            catch (error) {
                // Present error message to the user
            }
        }

        // ...
    }
    catch (error) {
        // Present error message to the user
    }
}
```

Depending on your use case, you may be able to use `async`/`await` simplify your code even further to prevent excessive nesting.

If you do decide to use `async`/`await` then you should be sure to read up on how the functionality works. Misuse of this feature can cause race conditions and other unexpected behavior that can be difficult to diagnose. Many blog posts and tutorials exist that describe the functionality better than I can here. A quick Google search popped up this one for example: https://javascript.info/async-await.

Comment: Lovely answer, It acctualy already is a function, I'll try to refactor my code, and if it works I mark as correct, thank you

Comment: @SpaceDogCS He gave you the idea already. Whether it works or not, you should mark his answer as chosen.

Comment: @amedina yes, true, sorry for my mistake